# MapKit pin title not visible when placed on overlay?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

When I place a pin on top of an overlay, the title of the pin appears to be obscured. When the pin is placed over a point that is not on top of the overlay, the title appears below the pin.

The string lastCoordName is the title of the pin; this string is passed from the previous view controller to the current one (shown below).

Here are some images to describe what I'm talking about...

[image: title shown]
Above image shows the title right below the pin ("360") when the pin is off the overlay.

[image: title not shown]
But the title goes away when the pin is moved to the correct position on top of the overlay.

The title is still shown when the polyline is drawn horizontally and terminates off the overlay, so the problem isn't that the line is covering the title.

Here is the custom pin class:

```
class CustomPin : NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var title: String?

    init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, title: String) {
        self.coordinate = coordinate
        self.title = title

        super.init()
    }
}
```

The relevant part of viewDidLoad()

```
    let pin = CustomPin(coordinate: endPoint, title: lastCoordName)//uses lastCoordName from previous vc (insead of looking up name of last node given coord)
    mapView.addAnnotation(pin)
    mapView.selectAnnotation(pin, animated: true)
```

And the mapViewController extension

```
extension mapViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        if overlay is SchoolMapOverlay {
            return SchoolMapOverlayView(overlay: overlay, overlayImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "GBSF1"))
        } else if overlay is MKPolyline {
            let lineView = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
            lineView.strokeColor = UIColor(red:0.2, green:0.48, blue:1.00, alpha:1.0)
            lineView.lineWidth = 10.0
            return lineView
        }
        return MKOverlayRenderer()
    }

    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        let pin = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "pin")
        pin.canShowCallout = true

        return pin
    }
}
```

Is the overlay covering the pin title? If so, why are the pin and its title not on the same level (above the overlay)?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the layer the overlay is drawn on with
`mapView.add(tileOverlay, level: .aboveRoads)`

This will draw it above roads but below labels. Problem is, it's below all labels; so depending on what you're showing in your map, you're gonna have to play with labels a bit.

[MKOverlayLevel Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkoverlaylevel)